# Python input error: NameError: name 'test' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a noob at python and just started to learn this.  I am trying to follow the book automate the boring stuff with python practical programming for total beginners but receiving error on my first excersise.  The book is using python 3 and I am using python 2.7.6

I have tried to change it by putting brackets or taking brackets off but unable to figure it out.  Please help in regards to this.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "first.py", line 5, in <module>
    myName = input()
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'test' is not defined
```

**Code Written:**

```
print "Hello world"
print "What is your name?" #ask for their name
myName = input()
print "nice to meet you, " + myName
print "the length of your name is:"
print (len(myName))
print "What is your age?" # asking for age this time
myAge = input()
print "You will be " + str(int(myage) +3) + "in three years."
```

Comment: Use `raw_input`, not `input`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing you are using `Python 2.x` (as you are using `print` statements).

In Python 2.x , `input()` function tries to evaluate the inputted value before returning, so when you input `test` , it tries to find the variable/name `test` causing the issue.

Use `raw_input()` instead of `input()` .

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. It works for me! I did not realize there was a difference in input in 2.7 and 3.

Answer (score 3):

In python 2 you should use `raw_input()` for getting a string from input.the `input` function is equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))` which evaluate your input.

And in this case when you print `'test'` it would be variable `test` which you didn't specify any value for it (didn't initialize it) and so it raises a `NameError`.

For example :

```
>>> print myval
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'myval' is not defined
```

But if I initialize it, the `print` function will print its value :

```
>>> myval=3
>>> print myval
3
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  It works for me!  I did not realize there was a difference in input in 2.7 and 3.